# Searching from parsed data in swift 3

Tags: iphone, swift

[image]I had a struct merchant in that I had a member post which is dictionary type in that I had name field. So, i want to filter name  starting with some text entered in textfield(shouldChangeCharactersIn range textfield delegate). how I can use predicate in this scenario. 
For example: I have six name "Pro shop", "table", "Pro merchnat", "Football", "Shop2", "mobile". then i type "pr" then it should give me result "Pro shop", "Pro merchnat".

```
struct Merchant {
var key: String
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference
   var merchant_id: String
var uniquecode: String
var post: NSDictionary

init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    ref = snapshot.ref
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    merchant_id = snapshotValue["id"] as? String ?? ""
    uniquecode = snapshotValue["uniqueCode"] as? String ?? ""
    post = snapshotValue["post"] as! NSDictionary   
}
```

Here is my code what i am trying to do that..

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    for item in merchantArr {
         var filteredMerchant = merchantArr.filter{((($0[item] as![String:Any])["post"] as! [String:Any])["name"] as! String).contains(string)}
    }
   return true
}
```

Comment: You want to implement search? or sort?

Comment: i want to implement search on behalf of name

Comment: I can't any name field in your code

Comment: It's name field in post dictionary for that i have not made any struct.

Comment: As always, do not use `NSDictionary` in Swift at all. You are fighting the strong type system. Use native Swift `Dictionary` and the `filter` function

Comment: can you show the json? or structure?

Comment: I have added the json.

Comment: every merchant will have multiple post or not? or you want to show only merchant having post.name = `xyz`

Comment: No, only single post with each merchant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var filteredMerchant = merchantArray.filter{((($0["merchant1414124"] as![String:Any])["post"] as! [String:Any])["name"] as! String).contains("pr")}
```

Comment: I am getting compile error" Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11" when i add this code of line.

Comment: Where are you adding this? and can you expand your code. So I could tell you where to put this code or alternative

Comment: Rock I am sorry i got busy with other section.Here is code what i am doing
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        for item in merchantArr {
             var filteredMerchant = merchantArr.filter{((($0[item] as![String:Any])["post"] as! [String:Any])["name"] as! String).contains(string)}
        }
       return true
    }

Comment: @RahulGupta add the code to the question. so its easier to read.
Never add code in comments section.